# No color with Panda3d

Tags: python-3.x, panda3d

I realize a simple model of 2 colors (black horn with a yellow support) with Blender 3.0.0 which I export in * .0bj. When I open it with the 3D viewer I can see the colors appear. But, when I call it in Python (I use Pycharm 2021.3 and the 3D engine Panda3d 1.10.10) the model appears white. Moreover, it is no longer vertical but horizontal. See attached images.

[With 3D Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9SGe.png)

[With Pabda 3D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G154D.png)

```
from panda3d.core import loadPrcFile, AmbientLight
```

loadPrcFile("config/conf.prc")

from direct.showbase.ShowBase import ShowBase

class MyGame(ShowBase):

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    pion = self.loader.loadModel("Models/Pion2.obj")
    pion.setPos(0, 15, -1.5)
    pion.reparentTo(self.render)
```

game = MyGame()

game.run()

Can you tell me how to get my 2 colors on my model with Panda3d ?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know about obj files. But if you are using gltf or glb files then you can get the texture by doing this

1.pip install panda3d-gltf
2.pip install panda3d-simplepbr

then in the main.py or whatever

import simplepbr

inside your game class

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    
    simplepbr.init()

    pion = self.loader.loadModel("Models/Pion2.glb") # or use gltf
    pion.setPos(0, 15, -1.5)
    pion.reparentTo(self.render)
```

after doing these you could see the texture in the model

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar experience with `.obj` files in Panda3D that had been exported from Blender. However, I found that exporting in the `.dae` format from Blender the texture is more likely to be preserved.